# How does the functions differ from objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this habit of using `function id(_id) { return document.getElementById(_id); }` as to lessen the work of typing this over and over.

**sidenote:**

> jquery becomes too heavy for small tasks and projects

As I  learnt Javascript more I came to know that we can pass around functions just like objects so we can do

```
var id = document.getElementById;
```

It seems like both do the exact same thing. However, I am not an expert in Javascript, so could there be any difference internally? and which is the preferred way of using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the context is:

```
const log = console.log;

log("test");
```

The upper wont work because the context changed, and log must be called on a *console* object, not on window ( aka without context). However, there are easy workarounds:

```
const log = console.log.bind(console);
```

Or you use functions, for example the arrow ones:

```
const log = (...args) => console.log(...args);
```

Comment: So to say to avoid confusion, using functions is better and safer.

Comment: @gauravP yes, or bind.